# How to solve the problem that clion keeps processing?

Tags: cmake, clion

when i try to modify my CMakeLists or compile a project, it gives the warning: processing ( Code analysis has been suspended. Heavy operation is running. ) Then I cannot compile my project.
The version of clion is 2021.3.2. And the cmake_minimum_required is version 3.21

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
```

The clion project occupy huge part of the CPU.

The project I want to compile is simple just like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("hello2!");
return 0;}
```

The Cmakelists is properly written:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(test C)

add_executable(test
    hello2.c)
```

I try to compile the project in Linux and it success. (Ubuntu 20.04 VMware Workstation) . But it always fail in Windows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8j0O.png)

Also, the project can be compiled successfully when I open it at first without doing any changes. After I do some simple changes, it shows processing and fails to compile. But I can save these changes and open it as a clion project to enable it to compile.

Comment: Hi and welcome ! Could you please add a few more helpful clarifications to your question ? (for example: what project are you trying to compile? If it's not too verbose, getting an idea of what CMakeLists.txt looks like might help. Does the configure step complete ? Are you getting any errors ? If so, can you post them ?). Currently there isn't enough information for others to help.

Comment: I add some details and codes to subscribe the question. The errors clion give are in the picture. I have no mistakes in my .c project. Maybe the problem is related to the hardware instead of the software? （I have little knowledge about harware）

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved. I changed my regedit by mistake for some reasons. After I reinstall the system(windows10). This problem disappear.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32965174)